@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function for TrailingIcon
Currently im learning jetpack compose and ive run in multiple errors like the one i stated above.
From posts on here i learned, that you cant use @Composables in, for example, "functions" like onClick.
That answered atleast a part of my questions about this error, but one still sticks out.
Right now im writing a code for a DropDownMenu and its using TrailingIcon and i get the same message. Im guessing it might be because the value (TrailingIcon) isnt a compatible value for TextField.
Anyone have an idea what i should do? If its a wrong value type, which one should i use?
Thanks in advance!


Please post your code as text, not as an image. Then we can copy it to an IDE and run it for ourselves which helps us figuring out an answer to your question. Please make sure to properly format the code when you paste it.

In the official documentation of ExposedDropdownMenu, there is a code sample provided. I pasted it below, please especially check that you have used the correct material3 imports:
import androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenuItem
import androidx.compose.material3.ExposedDropdownMenuBox
import androidx.compose.material3.ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.MenuAnchorType
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier

val options = listOf("Cupcake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo", "Gingerbread")
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var text by remember { mutableStateOf(options[0]) }

ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    expanded = expanded,
    onExpandedChange = { expanded = it },
) {
    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor(MenuAnchorType.PrimaryNotEditable),
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {},
        readOnly = true,
        singleLine = true,
        label = { Text("Label") },
        trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
        colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
    )
    ExposedDropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
    ) {
        options.forEach { option ->
            DropdownMenuItem(
                text = { Text(option, style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge) },
                onClick = {
                    text = option
                    expanded = false
                },
                contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
            )
        }
    }
}

Particularly check that you have
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.material3.ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults

